# Connectionstring in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, dbcontext

I am doing mvc practice and create a simple page for fetch data from database. During practice I notice one thing I create this class:

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And in my *web.config* First I add this detail:

```
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="con" connectionString="Server=XYZ;Database=mvc1;uid=sa;pwd=abcd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

When I run this application it give me error that *there are invalid columns name*.

But after that I read about it on internet and I change the **con** to **EmployeeContext** the name of the class that I create and then its work fine. Like this:

```
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Server=XYZ;Database=mvc1;uid=sa;pwd=abcd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Now I want to know for the now I create just one single simple class and I have to give the class name in the connection string. Then is there this mean that I have to create everytime new connection string for each class???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sample you have different class model :

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set; }
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public int      ArtistId    { get; set; }
        public string   Title       { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price       { get; set; }
        public string   AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
        public Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
    }
}
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public partial class Genre
    {
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public string   Name        { get; set; }
        public string   Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that you have to adding App_data folder is a special directory in ASP.NET which already has the correct security access permissions for database access. From the Project menu, select Add ASP.NET Folder, then App_Data. 
After you create a new connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

and then a class covering the different DbSet your Application :using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you want to create a new class you have just to put on the DbSet into the last class.
You can find all the details here : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4